# Unknown server tag error for AutoCompleteExtender TextBox in Ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am trying to run an asp.net application with ajax, but when creating an AutoCompleteExtender textbox I get this error:

> Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender'

What would cause that?

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that the required "TagPrefix" is registered within the page’s directives section:

```
<%@ Register 
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**.aspx**
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Ajax AutoCompleteExtender without Webservice</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCountry"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" >
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

**.CS**
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;



[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCountries(string prefixText)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Country where CountryName like @Name+'%'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();enter code here
da.Fill(dt);
List<string> CountryNames = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
CountryNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
return CountryNames;
}
```